# Resubscribe Observers on onError - RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java

I have subscribed an observer as follows

```
public PublishSubject<ChannelModel> publisher = PublishSubject.create();

publisher.subscribe(observer);

Observer<ChannelListModel> observer = new Observer<ChannelListModel>() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(ChannelListModel model) {
        adapter.setChannels(model.getChannels());
    }
};
```

It works perfectly fine the first time I request data and display the same. But if request fails and as soon as the onError is called, the publisher will lose its observer. I want to **re-subscribe** to the same observer. So that when I retry the failed request, I can publish the result to the observer.

Comment: You can't retry a terminated `PublishSubject` as it will just keep emitting the terminal event. You have to use some other construct or never terminate a `PublishSubject`. Have a look  at [`RxRelay`](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxRelay).

Answer (score 0):

In order to re-subscribe an Observable on error, you should use [Retry](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/retry.html) operator. In RxJava, you can do it as follows

```
publisher
  .retry()
  .subscribe(observer);
```

After that subscription should be retried infinitely as long as error will be thrown.

You can also specify limit of possible retries like that:

```
publisher
  .retry(5)
  .subscribe(observer);
```

In the example above, subscriber will retry operation 5 times. When the error will be still persisted after 5 tries, then subscription will fail.

Comment: I tried using `retry()` method but still not able to subscribe again to the observable. Even tried `retryWhen` method. That too didn't work for me.